# iOS drawLinearGradient diagonal not working correctly when view is longer than width

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, linear-gradients, cagradientlayer

I can demonstrate the issue with this simple example.

I have a view which needs diagonal gradient which should start with one color at top left corner and change to another color at the bottom right corner. The following code shows my attempt:

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.saveGState()
        context.clip(to: rect)
        
        let topColor = UIColor.red
        let bottomColor = UIColor.green
        
        var tr = CGFloat(0), tg = CGFloat(0), tb = CGFloat(0), ta = CGFloat(0), br = CGFloat(0), bg = CGFloat(0), bb = CGFloat(0), ba = CGFloat(0)//top and bottom component variables
        topColor.getRed(&tr, green: &tg, blue: &tb, alpha: &ta)
        bottomColor.getRed(&br, green: &bg, blue: &bb, alpha: &ba)
        
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colorComponents: [tr,tg,tb,ta,br,bg,bb,ba], locations: [0.0, 1.0], count: 2)

        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsAfterEndLocation)

        context.restoreGState()
    }

}
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, in the bottom square, when height is same as width, it works fine. However, in the top rectangle, when the width is longer than height, it doesn't work correctly as the top right corner doesn't have any red whatsoever and the bottom left corner doesn't have any green whatsoever.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the desired result you need to calculate start and end points that connect a line that is perpendicular to the diagonal line through the rectangle. See the following diagram:

[image]

The following update to your code calculates the values for *dx* and *dy* which can be used to get the start and end points of the gradient.

```swift
class GradientView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        let topColor = UIColor.red
        let bottomColor = UIColor.green

        let ang = atan(bounds.height / bounds.width)
        let len = cos(ang) * bounds.height
        let dx = sin(ang) * len
        let dy = cos(ang) * len

        // Create the gradient using the two colors
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor] as CFArray, locations: nil)!

        // Draw the gradient basing the start and end points off of the
        // center of the rectangle.
        let start = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - dx, y: bounds.midY - dy)
        let end = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX + dx, y: bounds.midY + dy)
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: start, end: end, options: [ .drawsBeforeStartLocation, .drawsAfterEndLocation ])
    }
}
```

The following sample views (wide, tall, and square) demonstrate the desired output for all three cases:

```swift
let wgv = GradientView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100))
let tgv = GradientView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 400))
let sgv = GradientView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
```

The results are:

wgv:

[image]

tgv:

[image]

and sgv:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This works excellent and the explanation is helpful too. How did you "think" the explanation? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: From the documentation for `drawLinearGradient(_:start:end:options:)`: *"The color at location 0 in the CGGradient object is mapped to the starting point. The color at location 1 in the CGGradient object is mapped to the ending point. Colors are linearly interpolated between these two points based on the location values of the gradient."*

Comment: (cont'd) Another way to interpret that is that the gradient is drawn, line by line, perpendicular to the line provided by the start and end points. For your use case you want these lines of color to be parallel to the line drawn between the bottom-left and top-right corners of the rectangle. This means the points you give to `drawLinearGradient` need to form a line that is perpendicular to that desired diagonal. Picking the top-left and bottom-right points only gives you that perpendicular line when the rectangle is a square.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the layer is masking to bounds, you could use the max value between the width and the height as the reference value when creating the gradient.

Meaning, **always** create a square gradient, whose size is the max between those values.

This will make the gradient render at a 45 degree always, as opposed to what you are experiencing. The issue is not that the gradient is not drawing properly, but rather the slope is different because of the size.

Comment: This does not appear to be what the OP is trying to accomplish. The OP wants the red/green “dividing line” to always be from corner to opposite corner, not 45°.